# SQL Server : Insert into Relation Table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert, relational-database

I want to insert a tuple in my relation table named `R_Kitap_Al`. But I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Kitap_Al'.

But I don't have `Kitap_Al` table. I suppose this is my old name the table. because of that I get this error, but how can I fix it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Kütüphane;Integrated Security=True");

    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO R_Kitap_Al (SSN, Book_No, BaslamaTarihi, BitisTarihi) VALUES (@SSN, @Book_No, @BaslamaTarihi, @BitisTarihi)", conn);

    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SSN", sSNTextBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Book_No", book_NoTextBox.Text);
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookName",bookNameTextBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BaslamaTarihi", baslamaTarihiDateTimePicker.Value);

    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(baslamaTarihiDateTimePicker.Value);
    dt = dt.AddDays(0);
    bitisTarihiDateTimePicker.Value = dt.AddDays(15);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BitisTarihi", bitisTarihiDateTimePicker.Value);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    this.Hide();

    R_Kitap_Al kit = new R_Kitap_Al();
    kit.ShowDialog();

    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the table `R_Kitap_Al` have a trigger associated with it.  Could the trigger be wrong and accessing `Kittap_AI`?

Comment: You are rigth. Thanks . i forget in sql server that's why i work with VS

Comment: Thank you.  Please click the upvote and accept answer icons; this will improve both our reputations on the site.